# Upload zip file error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, uploadify

I am using Uploadify to upload multiple files in my ASP.NET MVC application. In the controller action, I need to check if one of the uploaded files is a zip file, and if yes, I need to check its contents. For the zip functionality I am using the ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.

When uploading a zip file from say my desktop, I am getting the following error:
Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\xyz.zip' on the following line of code:
                    **FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(Path.GetFullPath(fileData.FileName));
                    ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(fs);**

How do I get past this error?

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase fileData)
        {
            if (fileData != null && fileData.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                if (Path.GetExtension(fileData.FileName) == ".zip")
                {
                    FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(Path.GetFullPath(fileData.FileName));
                    ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(fs);

                    foreach (ZipEntry zipEntry in zf)
                    {

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var fileName = Server.MapPath("~/Content/uploads/" + Path.GetFileName(fileData.FileName));
                    fileData.SaveAs(fileName);
                    return Json(true);
                }
            }
            return Json(false);
        }
```

Comment: your desktop have nothing to do with the server directory -

Comment: yes, but then how do I check the contents of the .zip file w/o uploading it to the server first?

Comment: Maybe specifying a full path for the destination location might be a solution. The mentioned path is not really a path to storevuser uploaded files. Oermission problem?

Comment: you can not check the content before uploading on server - except if you make some super duper chrome plugin that work on client.

Comment: You cannot check contents before uploading... Processing is done on the server, thus requires uploading first.

Comment: have you tried System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath

Comment: Hey you have to save your zip file first then have to perform operation ..  ( Try this u will get idea   Start >> RUN >> C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\xyz.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpPostedFileBase.FileName` is the name of the file uploaded, not the location on the file stored on the server.  `HttpPostedFileBase` does not store the file on the server, only as a stream.  Your options are either open the stream in memory (if your 3rd party utilies allow for opening streams) or saving the file to a known location, then open it from that location.

Answer (score 0):

`Path.GetFullPath` gets a full path from the current directory.
That has nothing to do with your `HttpUploadedFileBase`, which isn't on disk.

You need to pass a stream instead of a file path.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if it is a zip file, you could always look at the content-type coming back.

```
application/zip
```

This might work for what you are trying to do. Also, just try and look at what the content-type, you might find something more specific to your needs.

Comment: Thanks, content-type check is good to find if it is a zip file or not. But my requirement is to look inside the zip file and see if it contains a specific file. If it does, I go ahead with the upload, else not.